# Header and footer for a book using: part on even page and chapter on odd page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design, books

My goal is to realize this layout for a book (possibly using fancyhdr, but I'm open to everything):

[image]

where the current layout is represented in grey. In other words, I want :

- to put the page numbering on the footer of each page (except part title pages)
- to put the name of the current part on even (non-special) pages (with the format shown in the picture: PART I: XXX) + a line under it
- to put the name of the current chapter on odd (non-special) pages (with the format shown in the picture: CHAPTER I: XXX) + a line under it

What I name "special pages" are the pages of part title or the first page of each chapter.

1. How to do that?
2. From a professional editor point of view, what alignments should I choose for the header on even pages (part title on the left/center/right?) and for the header on odd pages (chapter title on the left/center/right?) (is there a prefered/more "natural" alignment?)

Here is an example of a basic document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Note: this is a very preliminary attempt..., 
%Fancier solutions are welcome
%The page numbering does not work correctly
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepart} %How do I get the part name in capital letters
\fancyhead[RO]{\thechapter} %How do I get the chapter name in capital letters

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\part{Premiere partie}
\chapter{Premier chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\part{Deuxieme partie}
\chapter{Troisieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Quatrieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). Otherwise people may well guess the wrong class and so forth. Regarding placement, I usually incline to centering headers and footers for "two-sided" documents.

Comment: Not setting the height of the header rule to `0pt` would return you to the default which includes a rule for `fancyhdr`. What have you tried using `fancyhdr`? Have you tried anything? Nothing in your code even attempts to create the layout you describe.

Comment: Also, why do you particularly want to use `fancyhdr`?

Comment: @cfr: I changed the phrasing of the subject. Any other package is welcome. I added a very bad first guess too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[head=15pt, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\parttitle{}
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{%
\ifx\\#1\\% optional argument not present?
  \origpart{#2}%
  \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
\else
  \origpart[#1]{#2}%
  \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
\fi
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{Partie \thepart: \parttitle}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\part{Premiere partie}
\chapter{Premier chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\part{Deuxieme partie}
\chapter{Troisieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Quatrieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

You must edit the font style in `\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}` and `\fancyhead[LE]{Partie \thepart: \parttitle}`. Moreover, you maybe need works with `\thispagestyle{empty}` for white pages before new chapter and new part.

I put `%` before `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` due problems with online latex compiler. Also

Comment: You should not set `\headheight` manually in a document which uses `geometry` as it will throw `geometry`'s calculations. Instead, tell `geometry` that's what you want.

Comment: With online latex compiler appears warnning message related `\headheight` : " Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt."

Comment: Yes. You need to add `headheight=15pt` or whatever to the settings you pass `geometry`.

Comment: If I make `%\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}` in the document, appears the warnning message ... regards

Comment: Yes. You should add it to the options for `geometry`.

Comment: Ah ok, Now I understand ...

Comment: It is just that `geometry` needs to know the value or its calculations will not come out quite as they should.

Comment: Well I just type that for a quick response ...

Comment: But then people copy-paste your code and don't know it is wrong. Why can't you edit your answer to correct it? It is a very simple change.

Comment: Is possible make very short comments?

Comment: Edits, you mean? Yes. Should be.

Comment: No no, short comments here ...

Comment: They must be at least 15 characters, it seems. At least so it says when you start to write in the comment box.

Comment: Sad, I want make a comment with four characters ...

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you say you want. I am not sure it is what you want, but your mileage may vary.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[coh]{\rightmark}
\fancyhf[ceh]{\leftmark}
\fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername{} \thechapter: #1}}}
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\partname{} \thepart: #1}}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother
```

[image: part and chapter]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[coh]{\rightmark}
\fancyhf[ceh]{\leftmark}
\fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername{} \thechapter: #1}}}
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\partname{} \thepart: #1}}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \mainmatter

  \part{Premiere partie}
  \chapter{Premier chapitre}
  \lipsum
  \lipsum
  \lipsum
  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

The reason I'm not sure the above is what you want is because I think it looks peculiar when there is an empty page between chapters. You may disagree but, if not, you can eliminate them if you wish.

If you don't want headers on pages between chapters, but do want a page number, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,nextpage}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\cleardoublepage}{\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{plain}]}{\typeout{Chapters successfully patched for no headers on pages between chapters.}}{\typeout{Could not patch chapters to eliminate headers on pages between chapters.}}
```

If you don't want a page number either, change `plain` to `empty`.

My personal view, by the way, is that these headers are much too heavy and distracting. They are underlined, in all capitals and bang centre. I would recommend a more subtle approach which provides information without drawing the eye away from the content of the text. (Drop the rule or move the header to one side or the other and get rid of the capitalisation or....)

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\part` to issue `\partmark` instead of `\markboth{}{}`, similarly to how `\chapter` issues `\chaptermark`. Then it's just a matter of defining suitably those two macros.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\usepackage{lipsum}

%Note: this is a very preliminary attempt..., 
%Fancier solutions are welcome
%The page numbering does not work correctly
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`:
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand{\partmark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\partname\space\thepart~ #1}}{}%
  }
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markright{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\space\thechapter~ #1}}%
  }
}% end of \lowercase
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\H@old@part}% would be \@part without hyperref
  {\markboth{}{}}
  {\partmark{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\part{Premiere partie}
\chapter{Premier chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\part{Deuxieme partie}
\chapter{Troisieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Quatrieme chapitre}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note that a peculiar trick is needed in order to get the French colon in the headers. Basically, `\partmark` and `\chaptermark` are defined with an active version of the colon.

Since we do the patch after loading `hyperref`, we need to patch `\H@old@part` instead of `\@part.

Don't neglect the warning by `fancyhdr` about the head height; I added the suggested setting to the options for `geometry`.

[image]