# Header with book title and part name using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design, french

I am currently writing a book in french which is made of three parts (with \part{}). Using the fancyhdr package, I would like to have the tile of my book on the even pages and the name of the part (and not that of the sections inside it) on the odd pages. How can I achieve that, especially since the book's title ("Éléments de Géométrie") contains accents which are not rendered well by fancyhdr.

Here is a picture of these two problems, the title is not rendered properly (left) and that I would like to print only the name of the part and not that of the section (right).

[image]

```latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark{Éléments de Géométrie}}
\fancyhead[OL]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
```

For character encoding I use

```latex
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

It is important to note that sections name which include accents works fine, for example :
[image]

Comment: It's not a problem with fancyhdr, but with `input encoding`. Which one do you use?

Comment: \leftmark and \rightmark are generally set by \chapter and \section.  Best avoid them.  But your will need to store the Part and Title somewhere (\partname?).

Comment: @Bernard I've updated my question with the relevant informations.

Comment: Did you check the real encoding of your editor (which is ??)?

Comment: @Bernard I am using GNU Emacs, but I have managed to solve the encoding problem just by changing the order in which the packages are listed in the preamble.

Comment: Fine! B.t.w.,  the language option is now `french`, and it's recommended that it be declared via \documentclass, so as to make sure that all language-dependent packages be informed.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, I have updated my code according to your advice. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve both of my problems. I solved the encoding issue by making sure to declare this at the very beginning of my preamble :

```latex
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Then in order to have the name of the parts right I used this piece of code based on this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241683/199781) :

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Set up headers %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*\parttitle{}
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{%
\ifx\\#1\\% optional argument not present?
  \origpart{#2}%
  \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
\else
  \origpart[#1]{#2}%
  \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
\fi
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase{Éléments de Géométrie}}
\fancyhead[OL]{\nouppercase\parttitle}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
```

Here is the result :

[image]